# Detect WebM mime type in PHP with Fileinfo

Tags: php, mime-types, webm

My code use the [FileInfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) extension to detect file mime-type.

```
$finfo = new finfo();
$mimetype = $finfo->file($filename, FILEINFO_MIME);
```

This works well for most files I tested. However, it doesn't works for WebM file. I understand that FileInfo uses a *magic file* database. The same than the one used by the `file` command which is also unable to detect WebM mime type (on the same system).

I guess it should be possible to add WebM support to this *magic file*, but how?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the formal definition of the file format: http://www.optimasc.com/products/fileid/magic-format.pdf